# What can I use to replace white cheese in a roasted red peppers pate?

Tags: substitutions, cheese, vegan

So, there's something I usually prepare for myself. It's pretty straightforward (since I have 0 knowledge and skills in cooking). I add roasted red peppers (from a can), [white cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirene), onion, garlic & olive oil in a food processor and blend them to a smooth puree.

However I have a new friend who is vegan and I want them to try this, so I was wondering what can I use to replace the white cheese?

I suppose the cheese is kind of necessary & I cannot just skip it because it "softens the pepper's strong flavor".

Comment: there is such thing as vegan cheese

Comment: http://www.onegreenplanet.org/vegan-recipe/10-vegan-cheeses-that-will-knock-your-socks-off/

Comment: @KevinFischer make it an answer, don't answer it in the comments.

Comment: @Luciano Not really an answer.  Just a suggestion

Comment: We already have a question which is about vegan cheese substitutes in general, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/301. I wouldn't see this question as a duplicate, because white brine cheese tastes quite differently from yellow cheeses, but to anybody answering, please check first that your suggestion is not already posted in the more general question, or if it is present there, take care to explain why it is specifically good for white brine cheese and not as a generic cheese substitute.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is white vegan cheese.  What I would recommend is that you make it prior to serving it to your buddy, and taste it with the new vegan cheese and see if that's the taste you're aiming for.  A super quick Google search found "white vegan cheese" with no problem.  You might even find some at your nearest grocery store.

Answer (score 2):

You might try tofu, as in [this recipe](https://www.forksoverknives.com/recipes/red-pepper-coriander-sauce/#gs.u4N3hqo) or [this one](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/24926/tofu-and-red-pepper-spread/).  Simply [press the tofu](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-press-tofu-3376642) to remove excess water, then add to your recipe as usual.  Tofu and white cheese are both fairly mild in flavor, so you should be able to substitute one for the other without sacrificing the flavor of the finished dish.  Tofu is also readily available, and may be cheaper (it is in my area) than vegan cheeses or other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Use toasted pine nuts or walnuts instead of cheese. You might find you like it better than the cheese version, and you're not serving your friend an ersatz version of something they can't have. Also a little bit of parsley or basil if you want to get even fancier.